# How do I check that a docker host is in swarm mode?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

After executing this;

```
eval $(docker-machine env mymachine)
```

How do I check if the docker daemon on `mymachine` is a swarm manager?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could also use `docker info` to see the result of `Swarm` property (`inactive` or `active`).

For example:

```
function isSwarmNode(){
    if [ "$(docker info | grep Swarm | sed 's/Swarm: //g')" == "inactive" ]; then
        echo false;
    else
        echo true;
    fi
}
```

Comment: This is a nice function. I just think you may add a redirection  2>/dev/null after 'docker info', in order to prevent docker warnings to pile up with your true/false response

Comment: This is a great function for some automation I'm writing.

Comment: [`docker info --format '{{.Swarm.LocalNodeState}}'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50590287/52499) solution seems to be more in order.

Answer (score 43):

To check general swarm membership, my preferred method is to use the formatted output from `docker info`. The possible values of this are [currently inactive, pending, active, locked, and error](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/3a633a712c8bbb863fe7e57ec132dd87a9c4eff7/api/types/swarm/swarm.go#L177):

```
case "$(docker info --format '{{.Swarm.LocalNodeState}}')" in
  inactive)
    echo "Node is not in a swarm cluster";;
  pending)
    echo "Node is not in a swarm cluster";;
  active)
    echo "Node is in a swarm cluster";;
  locked)
    echo "Node is in a locked swarm cluster";;
  error)
    echo "Node is in an error state";;
  *)
    echo "Unknown state $(docker info --format '{{.Swarm.LocalNodeState}}')";;
esac
```

To check for manager status, rather than just a node in a cluster, the field you want is `.Swarm.ControlAvailable`:

```
docker info --format '{{.Swarm.ControlAvailable}}'
```

That will output "true" for managers, and "false" for any node that is a worker or not in a swarm.

To identify worker nodes, you can join to two:

```
if [ "$(docker info --format '{{.Swarm.LocalNodeState}}')" = "active" \
     -a "$(docker info --format '{{.Swarm.ControlAvailable}}')" = "false" ]; then
  echo "node is a worker"
else
  echo "node is not a worker"
fi
```

Comment: This is a nice answer and the solution that fits best.

Comment: This worked great for me, but I had it in a bootstrap script and found it a bit slow and therefore needed a more efficient method of accessing the value. I came up with `docker node inspect self --format '{{.Spec.Availability}}'`

Answer (score 9):

I don't have a swarm node handy at the moment, but it looks as if you could simply run something like `docker node ls`.  When targeting a docker daemon that is *not* in swarm node, that results in:

```
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

And it returns a nonzero exit code

```
$ echo $?
1
```

So the test would look something like:

```
if docker node ls > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo this is a swarm node
else
  echo this is a standalone node
fi
```

Comment: As @MarcelloRomani points out, this test fails in worker nodes. As written in https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/ , there are 2 types swarm node; manager node & worker node.  And worker node cannot execute "docker node" (and some other swarm related) command even though it's swarm node. So, I recommend to see "docker info" command output.

Answer (score 1):

To get the IP address of a manager from any node (either worker or manager) using  bash you can do:

```sh
read manager_ip _ <<<$(IFS=':'; echo $(docker info --format "{{ (index .Swarm.RemoteManagers 0).Addr }}"))
echo "${manager_ip}"
```

As mentioned above, the most direct way to identify if the current node is a manager is by using:

```sh
docker info --format '{{.Swarm.ControlAvailable}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to larsks answer, if you run `docker node ls` when pointing to a worker node, you'll get the following message:

> Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Worker nodes can't be used to view or modify cluster state. Please run this command on a manager node or promote the current node to a manager.

You can use this to differentiate between worker nodes and nodes not in a swarm at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your docker environment variables are set properly

$env | grep DOCKER_

Compare url and port values with the output from

$docker-machine ls

Select the swarm master machine name and you can reset the environment variables using

$eval $(docker-machine env your_master_machine_name)

Once environment variables are set properly, your command

$docker info | egrep '^Swarm: ' | cut -d ' ' -f2

should give the correct result